# Count value from a Python list in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a Python list `my_list` with various values :

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

I want to query a MongoDB with PyMongo :

- counting the number of documents per item in the list
- counting the total number of documents

I can do it step by step, with a loop as follow :

```
for item in my_list:
   db.collection.find({"item" : item}).count_documents()
```

However, I would like to know a better way to do it, specifically avoiding loops.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with an aggregate

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-jmCPjzfm6L)

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "item": {
        "$in": [
          "a",
          "b",
          "c"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$item",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the `$match` filtering documents with where `item` is in `["a", "b", "c"]``

Then the `$group` is counting documents for each item.

The SQL equivalent is :
`SELECT item, SUM(1) FROM collection GROUP BY item`